# No aparece las relacions que hago en mysql php

Tags: mysql, sql, wampserver

Estoy tratando de crear una relacion entre estas 3 tablas pero al momento ed verlo de forma grafia no aparece como si estuvieran relacionadas

CODIGO:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Suppliers (
    Code INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
    Nit VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    Entry_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Exit_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Supplier_Type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

--Categorias
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Categories (
    Code INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Entry_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Exit_Date DATE NOT NULL
);

--Medicamentos
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Medications (
    Code INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Lot VARCHAR(110) NOT NULL,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL,
    Purchase_Price DECIMAL(30, 2) NOT NULL,
    Sale_Price DECIMAL(30, 2) NOT NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Category_Code INT, -- Nueva columna para la clave foránea de Categorías
    Supplier_Code INT, -- Nueva columna para la clave foránea de Suppliers
    Entry_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Expiry_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Unit_of_Measure VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Shelf_Number INT NOT NULL,
    Shelf_Level INT NOT NULL,
    shelf_position_number INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Category FOREIGN KEY (Category_Code) REFERENCES Categories(Code),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Supplier FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_Code) REFERENCES Suppliers(Code)
);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En qué engine están esas tablas? Si es `MyISAM`, las relaciones no existen en ese engine. Verifica que todas sean `InnoDB`. Lo puedes revisar ejecutando un **`SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla;`**